# How to do induction on BinNums.Z in Coq/

Tags: coq

I'm trying to do a simple function that like this

```
Fixpoint find_0 (n : BinNums.Z) :=
  match n with
    Z0 => n
  | Zpos p => find_0 p
  | Zneg q => find_0 q
  end.
```

But `p` is `positive` and not `Z` so this is ill typed.

If I try

```
Fixpoint find_0 (n : BinNums.Z) :=
  match n with
    Z0 => n
  | Zpos p => find_0 (n - 1)
  | Zneg q => find_0 (n + 1)
  end.
```

then Coq can't verify that this is strong normalizing, the error

```
Recursive definition of find_0 is ill-formed.
In environment
find_0 : BinNums.Z -> BinNums.Z
n : BinNums.Z
p : positive
Recursive call to find_0 has principal argument equal to 
"n - 1" instead of a subterm of "n".
Recursive definition is:
"fun n : BinNums.Z =>
 match n with
 | 0 => n
 | Z.pos _ => find_0 (n - 1)
 | BinInt.Z.neg _ => find_0 (n + 1)%Z
 end".
```

What to do in this situation?

Regards

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the definition of Bignums.Z:

```
Inductive Z : Set :=
    Z0 : Z
  | Zpos : positive -> Z
  | Zneg : positive -> Z.
```

is not recursive, you cannot write recursive functions over it. Instead you write a simple non recursive `Definition` to handle the constructors of Bignums.Z and there you call recursive functions you define on positives. It is also good style to define the functions you need on positives separataely on positives.

Answer (score 3):

Every recursive function in Coq must clearly have a *decreasing aspect*.  For many inductive types, this decreasing aspect is provided naturally by the recursive structure of this inductive type.  If you look at the definition of `positive`, you see this:

```
Inductive positive : Set :=
xI : positive -> positive | xO : positive -> positive | xH : positive.
```

When an object `p` of type positive fits the pattern `xO q`, `q` is visibly smaller than `p`, if only as a piece of data (and here because the *agreed meaning* of `xO` is multiplication by 2, `q` is also numerically smaller than `p`).

When looking at the data type for `Z`, you see that there is no recursion and thus no visible decreasing pattern, where the smaller object would also be of type `Z`, so you cannot write a recursive function using the `Fixpoint` approach.

However, there exists an extension of Coq, called `Equations`, that will make it possible to write the function you want.  The trick is that you still need to explain that something is decreasing during the recursive call.  This calls for an extra object, a relation that is known to have no infinite path.  Such a relation is called well-founded.  Here the relation we will use is called `Zwf`.

```
From Equations Require Import Equations.
Require Import ZArith Zwf Lia.

#[export]Instance Zwf_wf (base : Z) : WellFounded (Zwf base).
Proof.
constructor; apply Zwf_well_founded.
Qed.

Equations find0 (x : Z) : Z by wf (Z.abs x) (Zwf 0) :=
  find0 Z0 := Z0; find0 (Zpos p) := find0 (Zpos p - 1);
  find0 (Zneg p) := find0 (Zneg p + 1).
Next Obligation.
set (x := Z.pos p); change (Zwf 0 (Z.abs (x - 1)) (Z.abs x)).
unfold Zwf. lia.
Qed.
Next Obligation.
set (x := Z.neg p); change (Zwf 0 (Z.abs (x + 1)) (Z.abs x)).
unfold Zwf. lia.
Qed.
```

There is a little more work than for a direct recursive function using Fixpoint, because we need to explain that we are using a well founded relation, make sure the `Equations` extension will find the information (this is the purpose of the `Instance` part of the script.  Then, we also need to show that each recursive call satisfies the decrease property.  Here, what decreases is the numeric value of the absolute value of the integer.

The `Equations` tool will gives you a collection of theorems to help reason on the `find0` function.  In particular, theorems `find0_equation1`, `find0_equation2`, and `find0_equation3` really express that we defined a function that follows the algorithm you intended.